# Выпадающее меню в Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap

Подскажите пожалуйста, как в Twitter Bootstrap сделать так, чтобы выпадающее меню выпадало не при клике, а при наведении на пункты?

Необходимо сделать для элемента [`dropdowns`](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns).

Answer (score 3):

Я не знаю как это сделать "чисто" на данном фрэймворке, но очевидно же, что меню выпадает когда у элемента li( с классом "dropdown") появляется класс "open". Можно использовать это и при наведении ([.hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)) на элемент li, добавлять ему класс "open", а потом удалять.

Как-то так:

```
$('.nav').children('.dropdown').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).addClass('open');
  },
  function(){
    $(this).removeClass('open');
  }
);
```

Это костыль, наверняка, это как-то уже реализовано в TB.

Answer (score 1):

Вот применительно к bootstrap. Разверните сообщение на весь экран, а то bootstrap адаптируется.

```js
$('li.dropdown').on('mouseenter', function(){
$(this).addClass('show');
});
$('li.dropdown').on('mouseleave', function(){
$(this).removeClass('show');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown link
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<body>
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

  <!-- jQuery first, then Tether, then Bootstrap JS. -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```