# Вопрос по bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, css

Доброго времени суток. Появился вопрос по bootstrap'у от twitter'а.
При создании выпадающего меню, чтобы посмотреть подпункты нужно кликнуть по главному пункту. А как можно сделать чтобы подпункты открывались при наведении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я уже отвечал на подобный вопрос. Посмотрите ответ [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/198181/html-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E-bootstrap).